# How can I send a POST request from onclick event of an elementor button widget using code?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, webhooks, elementor

I'm using wordpress with elementor, I have a button on my page that has a link to a #anchor (scrolls down on click). I want to add a POST request to my Make webhook. I followed the steps for the onclick event found in the officiale website (https://elementor.com/help/button-widget/), I set the class ID and CSS class of my button as My_Button, I then added an HTML widget after the button with this code inside:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  jQuery('#My_Button a').click(function(){

  $.post("my.make.webhook",
  {
    name: "Donald Duck",
    city: "Duckburg"
  },
  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
  });
});
</script>
```

I then added this code to the CSS of the theme (as written in the official website linked above):

```
/** Button Fix for Tag Manager (For Click Id triggering) **/ .elementor-button-content-wrapper {pointer-events: none;} .elementor-button span { pointer-events:none}
```

However it doesn't work at all, what am I doing wrong? Is there an other way to simply send a post request to my webhook from the click of that button? The data I send can be a simple variable.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have to first do setup for ajax request like method and json data type and all like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Thanks, could you give me a "filled" example? Like `data: "this",`
And where do I need to insert that code?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Refer this one you will get more idea